# Single AsyncHttpClient instance ConnectTimeoutException

Tags: android, android-async-http, loopj

I use [android-async-http](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http) in my project, and AsyncHttpClient static single instance, my code as follow step:

1. HttpURLConnection http request;
2. In first request success callback, use AsyncHttpClient to request another url;
3. Get ConnectTimeoutException as follows:

> 06-28 18:35:36.440 18638-19939/com.zebra.carcloud.example W/System.err: cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to daily.yuncar.zebred.com/139.196.2.83:7090 timed out
>   06-28 18:35:36.441 18638-19939/com.zebra.carcloud.example W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
>   06-28 18:35:36.441 18638-19939/com.zebra.carcloud.example W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:157)
>   06-28 18:35:36.441 18638-19939/com.zebra.carcloud.example W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.scheme.SchemeSocketFactoryAdaptor.connectSocket(SchemeSocketFactoryAdaptor.java:65)
>   06-28 18:35:36.441 18638-19939/com.zebra.carcloud.example W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
>   06-28 18:35:36.441 18638-19939/com.zebra.carcloud.example W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:145)
>   06-28 18:35:36.442 18638-19939/com.zebra.carcloud.example W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:131)
>   06-28 18:35:36.442 18638-19939/com.zebra.carcloud.example W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
>   06-28 18:35:36.442 18638-19939/com.zebra.carcloud.example W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
>   06-28 18:35:36.442 18638-19939/com.zebra.carcloud.example W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:860)
>   06-28 18:35:36.442 18638-19939/com.zebra.carcloud.example W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
>   06-28 18:35:36.442 18638-19939/com.zebra.carcloud.example W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequest(AsyncHttpRequest.java:146)
>   06-28 18:35:36.443 18638-19939/com.zebra.carcloud.example W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequestWithRetries(AsyncHttpRequest.java:177)
>   06-28 18:35:36.443 18638-19939/com.zebra.carcloud.example W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.run(AsyncHttpRequest.java:106)
>   06-28 18:35:36.443 18638-19939/com.zebra.carcloud.example W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
>   06-28 18:35:36.443 18638-19939/com.zebra.carcloud.example W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>   06-28 18:35:36.443 18638-19939/com.zebra.carcloud.example W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>   06-28 18:35:36.443 18638-19939/com.zebra.carcloud.example W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>   06-28 18:35:36.444 18638-19939/com.zebra.carcloud.example W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

I google for a while but couldn't find the reason, someone meet same question with me:[loopj issues 725](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/issues/725), but I set AsyncHttpClient timeout to 30000(default 10000), and still get ConnectTimeoutException after 30 seconds.

**Modify single instance to new AsyncHttpClient instance before second request, every thing will be OK. I don't know whether the HttpURLConnection operation effects the AsyncHttpClient or not.**

Comment: The library you are using uses the Apache HttpClient library, which is no longer supported by Android, for [good reason](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#apache-http-client-removal). Android suggests to use the [`HttpURLConnection`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) class from the `java.net` package, but as @apelsoczi suggested, it may be easier with another library such as [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).

Comment: I was facing similar issue but then figured out that I had network issues, causing connection timeout. I am using the same library in my android app and it is very well supported. Make sure you do not have any network issues and the server ULR is correct.